# How to add different coordinates using arcpy.da with InsertCursor

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I'm learning arcpy and I got stuck in what seems to be an easy step.

I have a Shapefile (Point geometry). I added a new row:

```
busStopsL1 = "C:/temp/geometries/Estacions_L1.shp"
xy = (6014912,2116582)
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(busStopsL1,("SHAPE@XY")) as cursor:
    cursor.insertRow([xy])
```

Then, I tried to add different coordinates at the same time:

```
busStopsL1 = "C:/temp/geometries/Estacions_L1.shp"
arrayCoordenades = [(6015581,2115858),(6015939,2115574),(6016239,2114585)]
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(busStopsL1,["SHAPE@XY"]) as cursor:
      for row in arrayCoordenades:
          cursor.insertRow(row)
```

It didn't work. I've been trying different options but I couldn't find the way to add these three coordinates at the same time. I saw some examples in ESRI help in which they add coordinates and information from others fields at the same time and it seems it's the same way I tried but...

Comment: You would have better luck moving this thread to the GIS site at  http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: It was the first time I added a question to this site so I didn't know how it works. Anyway, I found the answer to my own question. Thank you Aurora.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the tuple in a list, just like in your first example. Originally answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/131970/560

`cursor.insertRow([row])`

Comment: Hi, I found the answer after sending the question. Your'e right. Thank you Evan.

Answer (score 0):

```
import arcpy
fc = r'{feature class}'
fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
fieldsList = []
for field in fields:
    fieldsList.append(str(field.name))
query = {valid sql query}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fieldsList,where_clause=query) as searchCursor:
    for row in searchCursor:
        print (row)
        row[{insert tuple index of the x,y values}]
        newX = point[0] - 45
        newY = point[1] + 35
        newPoint = (newX,newY)
        t = row
        newRow = list(t)
        newRow[1] = newPoint
        t = tuple(newRow)
        insertCursor.insertRow(t)
del insertCursor
```